# How to apply Emojis to Angularjs directive list?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, emoji

I'm learning Angular JS and currently doing a chat app, I want to apply the Javascript conversion `.shortnameToImage(str)` offered by Emojione to the list of messages in the chat app on my front end.

This is on my html index the messages display

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index">    
    {{message}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

So, my intention is that everything in the `{{message}}` gets evaluates so if another user sends *:smile:* well the smile emoji shows up without involving the back end.

So far I've tried to use a javascript function that that evaluates the user input and makes the conversion to `li` element but works on the first message.

What's the best approach I can take to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real Angular way would be to create a `filter` yourself (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) or use existing https://github.com/globaldev/angular-emoji-filter. And then usage would be as simple as `{{message | emoji}}`.

Comment: Thanks for this direction seems like the most logic one. I tried to use it but lets say I sent a :smile: I should be getting back the smile emoji right? All I'm getting back is <i class='emoji emoji_smile'>smile</i> any idea what could be going on?

Comment: It is expected, as in my reply when using double curly braces the HTML is escaped thus outputting the source. Angular-emoji-filter expects you to use ``ng-bind-html-unsafe="message | emoji"`` instead. It will output raw HTML without escaping. BUT you need to take into account the security implications - https://github.com/globaldev/angular-emoji-filter/issues/7

Comment: Thanks a lot, took a slighltly different approach by using this filter angular-smilies [link](http://mistic100.github.io/angular-smilies/)  and since I am using Express JS as well I wasn't serving the modules files, it's working now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to reflect Sergio's comments**

Javascript is a good approach for this. You can cycle through all of your li elements with

```
var array_of_li =  document.querySelectorAll("ul.messages li");
```

You can then convert them with a simple loop.

```
var array_of_li = document.querySelectorAll("ul.messages li");
for (var i = 0; i < array_of_li.length; i++) {
    convert(array_of_li[i]);
}
```

And here's the conversion code based on the [emojione doc](http://git.emojione.com/demos/jsshortnametoimage.html) :

```
function convert(li_html) {
    var input = li_html.innerHTML;
    var output = emojione.shortnameToImage(input);
    li_html.innerHTML = output;
}
```

I've put all of that together in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvugf9zv/34/) and it displays a nice emoji smile.

Comment: This is not the kind of evaluation he meant.

Comment: Also, you probably meant `eval`, not `evaluate`.

Comment: I have updated my post after your comments, I hope I provided a good answer to the problem.

Comment: It's an improvement, but not really a good answer. He uses angular. Manually managing DOM from under it is an anti-pattern. Angular should be used all the way.

Comment: That's true. According to his post he tried to go that way too, so that piece of code could still be helpful. I don't have much experience in Angular so I'll leave it to the pros.

Answer (score -2):

Looking at their docs, it's pretty straightforward and there are no gotchas (if you managed to install it correctly, that is)

http://git.emojione.com/demos/jsshortnametoimage.html

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index">    
      {{ emojione.shortnameToImage(message) }}
   </li>
</ul>
```